# Webserver shows content of php-files instead of interpreting it

Tags: php, html, apache

I recently installed apache2 and Mysql on my RaspberryPi, I also setup FTP so I can edit my Files on my PC and upload them directly to the webserver.

If I now connect to my server vis it's IP-Address I can see the index.html, but as soon as I try to open a *.php file it shows the content of said file instead of interpreting it.

Are there any common mistakes that could make this happen?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Apache and MySQL doesn't mean you have installed PHP. Also if you did, you should config Apache to open .php ext's as PHP

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/2806497

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of errors mainly happen 3 reason

1. You may not be installed php
2. if you have installed php, you have not configured with apache
3. Check your php file having opening php tag `<?php` and closing php tag `?>`

Comment: The problem was that I THOUGHT I installed PHP when actually there occured an error during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing can happen if you have **short php tags disabled**. If it is disabled - all code that starts with `<?...`, `<?=...` will be printed on the screen just as simple text. Everything can be checked very easy: just create some php file and add `<?php echo phpinfo() ?>`. If browser will show php info - than problem is really in disabled short pho tags.

In that case you can simple enable that in `php.ini` with the directive `short_open_tag=On` (not recommended, however).

This is from `php.ini` file:

```
; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
; recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and
; instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use
; of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily
; confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because
; this short cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still
; supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP's response header should have "Content-Type:text/html". Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have PHP configured to interpret php files within Apache or the PHP module is not known to Apache.

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

or

```
apt-get install php5
```

in apache.conf (or similiar) add line like:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p[2-6]?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score 0):

Install php and any web server

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

download and install and goto C:/xampp/htdocs

make directory of your project and in browser type localhost/your_directory_name